# Powershell search for longfile path names and send the owner of a file a mail to do something about it

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set up a PowerShell script which reads out a UNC path on Windows and searches for longfiles/paths. After it has found the file it needs to send a mail to the owner of the file.

I have found already a script and tweaked it a bit but it doesn't seems to work yet. The following script can find the long file path now but the mail is not working properly.

```
    $limit = 90
    $testpath = "C:\test"
    $resultpath = "c:\test"
    $admins = "moh@test.com"
    $from = "moh@test.com"
    $smtpserver = "smtp.office365.com"

    Get-ChildItem -Path $testpath -Recurse | ?{$_.fullname.length -gt $limit} | 
    Select-Object fullname, 
        @{n="owner";e={
            $_.GetAccessControl().GetOwner('System.Security.Principal.NTAccount')}},
        @{n="namelength"; e={$_.fullname.length}} | 
    %{
    Out-File -FilePath "$resultpath\Longfiles of $($_.owner -replace "\\","-").txt" -Append -InputObject "$($_.namelength) - $($_.fullname)"
}
Get-ChildItem $resultpath -Filter "longfiles of *" | % {
    if($_.name -match "Longfiles\sof\s(.+)\.txt"){
        $user = $matches[1] -replace "-","\"
        $ntacc = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($user)
        $sid = $ntacc.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
        $aduser = [ADSI]"LDAP://<SID=$sid>"
        $email = $aduser.Properties.mail
        if($email) {Send-MailMessage -Attachments $_.fullname -Body "Please change the filenames of the files listed in the attached file to shorter!" 
            -From $from -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Subject "System notice" -To 
$email -cc $admins
        }
        else {
            Send-MailMessage -Attachments $_.fullname -Body "email coudn't be sent to owner" `
            -From $from -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Subject "System notice" -To $admins
        }
    }
    else {Write-Host "Some error with file $_"}
}
```

EDIT: This is what i see, after running the script... it is asking me to fill in the fields, while the fields are already filled in in the script such as (From: moh@test.com to moh@test.com)

[[image: This is what i see]]

Comment: Have you debugged it? Use proper error handling mechanisms to trap the exception, *hint* `try{ } catch { .... }`

Comment: What does "the mail is not working properly" mean?  Do you get an error message?  Does the email not send?  Does the email send but incorrectly?

Comment: Please see my comment below

Comment: If it is the `Send-MailMessage` on line 23 that is failing, it looks like you are missing the line continuation character at the end of lines 23 and 24 like you have at the end of line 28.

Comment: Fyi, the problem handling long file paths has been fixed a few Windows 10 builds ago (14393 if I remember correct), maybe there is no need for your script if you have an upgrade planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue was because of line breaks in the middle of a command. In some lines, you had a backtick character which escapes the end of the line. But as you found these are really easy to break and that's why it's [best practice](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/blob/master/Style-Guide/Code-Layout-and-Formatting.md#maximum-line-length) to use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx) on commands with many parameters.

I also changed your `Select-Object` calculated properties into a more readable `[pscustomobject]` since they are hard to format in a readable way, but this does require PS3+.

```
$limit = 90
$testpath = "C:\test"
$resultpath = "c:\test"
$admins = "moh@test.com"
$from = "moh@test.com"
$smtpserver = "smtp.office365.com"

Get-ChildItem -Path $testpath -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.fullname.length -gt $limit} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'fullname' = $_.fullname
            'owner' = $_.GetAccessControl().GetOwner('System.Security.Principal.NTAccount')
            'namelength' = $_.fullname.length
        }
    } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Out-File -FilePath "$resultpath\Longfiles of $($_.owner -replace "\\","-").txt" -Append -InputObject "$($_.namelength) - $($_.fullname)"
    }
Get-ChildItem $resultpath -Filter "longfiles of *" | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.name -match "Longfiles\sof\s(.+)\.txt") {
        $user = $matches[1] -replace "-", "\"
        $ntacc = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($user)
        $sid = $ntacc.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
        $aduser = [ADSI]"LDAP://<SID=$sid>"
        $email = $aduser.Properties.mail
        if ($email) {
            $mailparams = @{
                'Attachments' = $_.fullname
                'Body' = "Please change the filenames of the files listed in the attached file to shorter!"
                'From' = $from
                'SmtpServer' = $smtpserver
                'Subject' = "System notice"
                'To' = $email
                'cc' = $admins
            }
            Send-MailMessage @mailparams
        } else {
            $mailparams = @{
                'Attachments' = $_.fullname
                'Body' = "email coudn't be sent to owner"
                'From' = $from
                'SmtpServer' = $smtpserver
                'Subject' = "System notice"
                'To' = $admins
            }
            Send-MailMessage @mailparams
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "Some error with file $_"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line breaks or escape them with a backtick: `` ` ``.  Your script must actually look like this:

```
if ($email) {
    Send-MailMessage -Attachments $_.fullname -Body "Please change the filenames of the files listed in the attached file to shorter!" 
    -From $from -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Subject "System notice" -To 
    $email -cc $admins
}
else {
    Send-MailMessage -Attachments $_.fullname -Body "email coudn't be sent to owner" `
    -From $from -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Subject "System notice" -To $admins
}
```

And Powershell doesn't know that the line beginning with `-From` is part of `Send-MailMessage`.